# From where can we retrieve next_available_date for Available-to-Promise in Oracle-EBS?

Tags: oracle-ebs

I'm supposed to get **next_available_date** for an item from the backend. I'm able to see it in the frontend(application). The record history for that particular column is disabled. So I'm unable to figure from where they are getting it.

I've checked in mrp_atp_schedule_temp table. But I don't think it's where it is coming from. I've also tried the API in the below link, but it didn't help

https://oracleappstechblog.wordpress.com/tag/mrp_atp_pub-call_atp/

Comment: Is the frontend application Forms or OA Framework UI?  You can often reverse engineer which view it's coming from by looking at underlying code - but how to do that differs based on the techstack.

Comment: Frontend is application forms. It's probably getting data from the view MRP_ATP_SCHEDULE_TEMP_V.

I tried to get the date using the API in below link, but I'm not getting the correct link for all the orders:
https://oracleappstechblog.wordpress.com/tag/mrp_atp_pub-call_atp/